# MVC 3: Multiple Vars

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my HomeController Index action, I want to have two SQL queries:

```
var model = db.Task.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Completed == false) && (n.Due < dateTime));
return View(model);

var map = db.Events.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Start < dateTime));
return View(map);
```

In the code above, the second Var is underlined green. How do I go about performing both these queries and passing the results through to the home page?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from a function and expect the code after the return to execute.

Make sure you have a *single* model for the view that includes *all* of the needed information.

For example:

```
var model = db.Task.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Completed == false) && (n.Due < dateTime));
model.Map = db.Events.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Start < dateTime));
return View(model);
```

This code will not compile unless you have a `Map` member defined on your model.

Though instead of two DB calls, better approach would be to have all the data populated in one call.

Comment: I get a red line underneath ".Map" though

Comment: @dalehumphries - Of course you do. You need to change your model to include a `Map` property. The code I posted is illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, either create a class to hold both of your variables:

```
public class IndexModel {
    IEnumerable<ModelA> Model { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<MapMode> Map { get; set; }
}
```

And in your action:

```
return View(new IndexModel{ Model = model, Map = map });
```

Or put one of the items into the view data bag.

```
ViewBag.Map = map;
return View(model);
```